Can I use the same relay to switch 220V and detect 24V connection?
I am rather new here and unknown to much of the terms being used, I realize, sorry for that!
I have Schneider A9C30212 relays I use to switch lights on/off. I use 24V signals throughout the house for detecting light switches pressed, PIR sensors etc and for triggering relays. Most places I only switch one wire to a light. The relay switches 2 wires at the same time.
I use A1/A2 for the 24V signal that triggers the relay. Connections 1/2 go to the light.
Can I safely use 3/4 to connect a 24V wire connected to a Phidget board, so that my system can detect if this switch is on or not? Or do I risk current "jumping over" somehow?
The datasheet can be found here: https://www.se.com/il/en/product/A9C30212/impulse-relay-itl-2p-2-no-16a-coil-24-vdc-48-vac-50-60hz/, but I don't know how to read anything useful out of it to answer my question?
I am thankful for suggestions about other solutions, but these are already installed and changing all of them would be costly. So my question is simply: would it be safe or not to connect the 24V detection as described here?
The 24V adapter I use is this: https://www.clasohlson.com/no/Batterieliminator-27-W/p/39-1512 . No idea if it is PELV, SELV or whatever, not sure we use this terms here in Norway? And I realize I might be wrong, but does that really make a difference for the answer to my question?
The problem today is that if power goes down, the system can't know when it restarts if lights are on or off.

After realizing that the part nr is A9C30212 (60669-2-2 is a standard), I found the datasheet: https://www.se.com/il/en/product/A9C30212/impulse-relay-itl-2p-2-no-16a-coil-24-vdc-48-vac-50-60hz/ . But I have no idea what there can tell me what I asked?

@Knut please update your post with the new information and the new question ... it does not belong in a comment

Thank you! I'm new here, didn't quite know how to do this.

This 24VDC  is that PELV SELV or FELV ?

You probably want a relay with auxillary contacts for the ELV (24V)  circuit that have terminals which are well segregated from the LV (220V) circuit. terminals.

consider using a pulse or latching relay instead of an impulse relay,  latching relay use different signals to turn on and off, so the controller can command the relay into a known state.

Thanks for all answers so far, people! I really appreciate it, but I have edited the question to hopefully clarify what I am asking (and my level of ignorance about these topics)!

No, not remaining within the relay's specifications.
Switching DC is much harsher on a relay than switching AC, because arcs that form from DC won't self-extinguish from a zero crossing (because, of course, DC has no zero crossings). As such, relays must be separately rated for DC operation, and it is not safe to assume that a relay rated to switch 250 V AC is capable of switching any amount of DC at all.
Relays rated for both 250 V AC and something like 30 to 50 V DC are not uncommon, and this one probably would have no trouble switching 24 V DC, but as it does not make any mention of DC in its datasheet, using it to switch DC is technically exceeding its specifications. In particular, using it for a permanent installation in a building as your question implies would probably be against electrical code, and would probably be grounds for a denial of insurance coverage should your house burn down.
Just get a relay that's actually rated for both AC and DC.

Thank you! Admittedly, I don't follow everything you write. I thought switching itself is a purely mechanical thing, no matter was is attached? I mean, it switches without anything attached, so why would it care if there was 220V AC or 24V DC running in the wires? So I was expecting the only problem to be the possibility of arcs between the two different wire sets. Further explanation would be appreciated, but your insurance comment made me realize that I would anyway have to check this with my electrician. If he doesn't approve and accept the setup, I won't risk any insurance trouble.

Not under 3.3/5V, the low voltage here is 24V DC.

@Knut The potential issue is arcs forming while the contacts are opening. Arcs between poles are very well protected against, but arcs from one contact of a pole to another are another matter entirely--once an arc forms, it's much easier to maintain the arc than to form it in the first place, and an arc can form much more easily when the contacts are only a fraction of a millimeter apart, before they've fully opened.

@Burglups 3.3 V or 5 V I wouldn't be too worried about; 24 V I would be. It's probably fine, but I couldn't in good conscience recommend it for a permanent installation in a building. It could also lead to nuisance tripping of arc-fault breakers, if there are any on the DC side of this 24 V system.

@Burglups I don't see any mention of 2 mA. The link to the 24 V power supply seems to say it's rated for 27 W, which is a bit over 1 A continuous. Easily enough to wear out a relay quite rapidly. And, when you get to permanently-installed systems, you need to be very careful about what's legal and to code, not just what's safe. If Knut's house were to burn down for any reason at all, including reasons with nothing to do with electricity, an insurance company could use this electrical system operating out of spec as grounds to deny the claim. Yes, that's ridiculous, but it does happen.

@Burglups And DC really is that much harder on a relay than AC. If an arc forms in an AC relay, it's all but guaranteed to be extinguished after no more than one half-cycle (10 ms in europe, 8.33 ms in north america), which puts a hard limit on how much damage it can do. DC, on the other hand, can arc indefinitely--and for a relay with sufficiently short clearance when open, 1 A at 24 V is more than enough to keep the arc going once it gets started.

@Burglups Damage due to arcing will also be concentrated on one contact in the case of DC, where in AC it will be random on each switching event (based on whether it's on a positive half-cycle or negative half-cycle when the switch opens). All this adds up to being the reason why relays typically have either no DC breaking rating or a much lower DC rating than their AC rating (250 V AC / 30 V DC is not uncommon, for instance).

@Burglups I have no idea what a phidget board is, nor how much current it needs. My point is primarily regulatory, in addition to the attempt to head off a common and dangerous misconception about relay ratings, and the fact that you seem to be deliberately ignoring especially the regulatory part of it is, honestly, quite frustrating. Regulations do not care that something was being used in a safe manner, and insurance companies will look for any way out of paying a claim.

Some clarification: the wires I would be connecting to the relays would be connected to the inputs of Phidget boards (phidgets.com), which is specified to draw 2mA. Thanks to good descriptions here, I see that everyone agrees that arcs between the two "lines" here is not a problem. And with 2mA, I can't see arcs between the poles of the 24V line is any problem, either. No, I am not an electrician, but my electrician has checked and approved of letting me do what I like on the 24V side. I will contact him for final approval before I connect 24V to these relays.
